# How to force VBA to add new line in XML body?

Tags: xml, vba

I am looking for some assistance. I am currently in the middle of building an XML file via VBA. I get to the point where I need to add multiple records but the thing is, every record has a different name. It doesn't make sense to me to create it in Excel, column by column because it can be a hundred records or none of them. I don't have an API to that either.

How to force in VBA to create extra line like mentioned in example below?

I downloaded XML directly from the website, and this is how it looks like this:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dpiva version="05" xmlns="http://www.at.gov.pt/schemas/dpiva">
    <rosto>
        <apuramento>
            <btBensUELiquidadoDeclarante></btBensUELiquidadoDeclarante>
            <btBensUETotal></btBensUETotal>
            <btImportDeclarante></btImportDeclarante>
            <btOperacoesIsentasComDeducao></btOperacoesIsentasComDeducao>
            <btOperacoesIsentasSemDeducao></btOperacoesIsentasSemDeducao>
            <btServicosUE></btServicosUE>
            <btTaxaNormal></btTaxaNormal>
            <btTotal></btTotal>
            <btTransmissoesUEIsentas></btTransmissoesUEIsentas>
            <ivaARecuperar></ivaARecuperar>
            <ivaBensUELiquidadoDeclarante></ivaBensUELiquidadoDeclarante>
            <ivaBensUETotal></ivaBensUETotal>
            <ivaDedutivelExistenciasTaxaNormal></ivaDedutivelExistenciasTaxaNormal>
            <ivaDedutivelImobilizado></ivaDedutivelImobilizado>
            <ivaDedutivelOutros></ivaDedutivelOutros>
            <ivaDedutivelTotal></ivaDedutivelTotal>
            <ivaFavorEstadoTotal></ivaFavorEstadoTotal>
            <ivaFavorSujPassivoTotal></ivaFavorSujPassivoTotal>
            <ivaImportDeclarante></ivaImportDeclarante>
            <ivaServicosUE></ivaServicosUE>
            <ivaTaxaNormal></ivaTaxaNormal>
            <regularizacoesFavorEstado></regularizacoesFavorEstado>
            <regularizacoesFavorSujPassivoNaoComunicadasCobranca></regularizacoesFavorSujPassivoNaoComunicadasCobranca>
            <temOperacoesAdquirenteComLiqImposto></temOperacoesAdquirenteComLiqImposto>
            <temOperacoesComLiqImposto></temOperacoesComLiqImposto>
            <temOperacoesDedutiveis></temOperacoesDedutiveis>
            <temOperacoesSemLiqImposto></temOperacoesSemLiqImposto>
        </apuramento>
    </rosto>
    <anexoCampo40R>
        <regularizacoes>
            <campo40Total></campo40Total>
            <listaNum2E3E6>
            </listaNum2E3E6>
        </regularizacoes>
    </anexoCampo40R>
</dpiva>
```

Comment: What's your question? Where did you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to put into <listaNum2E3E6>, multiply items consider the fact that every time, if you want to add new position, it needs to be listed as:                <listaNum2E3E6  row="1" and so on.

Comment: Can share your VBA code and point the place where you are stuck?

Comment: </listaNum2E3E6>
<listaNum7Antes2013Item row="1"> - this is where I'm stuck. Every single record for that list, needs to have an unique number of row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a 'string-based' approach, you can achieve it by simply building a string having the desired `xml` structure:

```
Public Sub Create_listaNum2E3E6()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim artigoValue As String
    Dim s As String

    artigoValue = "01" 
    
    s = "<listaNum2E3E6>" & vbNewLine
    For i = 1 To 10
        s = s & "   <listaNum2E3E6Item row=" & Chr(34) & i & Chr(34) & ">" & vbNewLine
        s = s & "       <artigo>" & artigoValue & CStr(i) & "</artigo>" & vbNewLine
        s = s & "   </listaNum2E3E6Item>" & vbNewLine
    Next i
    s = s & "<listaNum2E3E6>"

    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

You can replicate the code to get the `<listaNum7Antes2013>` tag as well.

The `i` variable will increment the row attribute, you also need to take care of the data (values of `<artigo>` tags, in the code there is a dummy value given). You can pass them to the procedure/function body in an array and use `LBound` and `UBound` as your iterator (instead of `i`).